# Open new browser window from popup

Tags: javascript, html, browser, popup

I have a webpage (A) that opens a popup (P).

In P, I have a link that must open a new _blank target page in the original browser instance (the one with page A).

How can I accomplish this?
I've tried some solutions based on `window.open()` but I am not sure how to apply them.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try `window.opener.location.href` to set the parent window location to the new url which you wanted to open in the parent.

Comment: Thank you, that's sweet. Any concerns about browser compatibility?

Comment: i believe it is compatible as long as both pages are on the same domain, so that you don't end up with cross domain issues.